# Индекс строки, которая содержит минимальное значение

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Используется Python, Имеется dataframe, в нем с помощью функции min нахожу минимальное значение `df['col1'].min()`. Минимальное значение может содержаться в нескольких строках.
Подскажите, как узнать *индекс* строки, которая содержит минимальное значение.

Comment: pandas.Series.idxmin

Comment: Этот пример возвращает минимальный индекс, а не индекс минимального значения

Comment: `s = pd.Series([2, 17, -1, 34, 45]); s.idxmin()` выводит 2, а не 0

Comment: Если вы желаете получить номер строки, но у вас не последовательная индексация, то вы можете использовать `series.values.argmin()`. Но вообще смысла в этом большого (ровно как и маленького) я не вижу.

Comment: @EzikBro, может оформите в виде ответа ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большое спасибо.
Пример кода для поиска индекса минимального значения

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
 'restaurant_id': [101,102,103,104,105,106,107],
 'address': ['A','B','C','D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
 'city': ['London','London','London','Oxford','Oxford', 'Durham', 'Durham'],
 'sales': [10,500,48,12,21,10,14],
 'my': [1,-1,48,-12.0,21,16,12]
})

print(df[df['city']=='Durham'][['sales','my']].idxmin())
```

результатом будет индексы минимальных значений строк если 'city' == 'Durham'

```
sales    5 #значение 10
my       6 #значение 12
dtype: int64
```